# Route is not calling rest webservice

Tags: ember.js

I have started a simple example using the fixture Adapter. When I navigate to my route /teams, I can see all Teams i have registered in my adapter.

Now I changed my code to register the Default restadapter:

```
Football.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    host: "http://localhost:8080/MatchService.svc/json"
});
```

When I now navigate to my route /Teams, I can see no Errors, the site looks as it should, just without no Teams listed in the list.

Then I started to have a look at the Network-Traffic: No calls are being sent, nothing.

But: When I try to add a team (I havent implemented this Method in rest service yet), I can see that there is a call going to 
    localhost:8080/MatchService.svc/json... 
and offcourse, I get a 404.

But why dont I get a call against 
    localhost:8080/MatchService.svc/json/teams 
when I navigated to my Teams-route?

Here is my route:

```
Football.TeamsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.all('team');
  }
});
```

I changed it already from this.store.find .... to this.store.all... because after using the restadapter I got an "error while loading the route : undefined".

I also added the current ember.js -Version as reference from the ember site.

Thats the json which gets returned by the Server:

```
{"TeamsResult":[
    {"ID":1,"Name":"Deutschland"},
    {"ID":2,"Name":"Frankreich"}
]}
```

I also tried a a not wrapped json result from the WebService:

{[{"ID":1,"Name":"Deutschland"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Frankreich"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` doesn't make a call to the server, it just returns all of the records already fetched client side.  you should use `this.store.find('team')`

Additionally you should define your adapter using `extend`:

```
Football.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: "http://localhost:8080/MatchService.svc/json"
});
```

`reopen` applies it to every instance created of the rest adapter, which may not be appropriate.

Here's a small example that shows the basic structure of your app:

```
Football = Ember.Application.create();

Football.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('teams', {path:'/teams'});
});

Football.TeamsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('team');
  }
});


Football.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: "http://localhost:8080/MatchService.svc/json"
});

Football.Team = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr()
});
```

For convenience sake I mocked the call to `http://localhost:8080/MatchService.svc/json/teams` with what Ember Data is expecting as a response:

```
  {
    teams:[
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Miami Heat"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Seattle Seahawks"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Texas Longhorns"
      }
     ]
  }
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/425/edit

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

What can I do, if the json returned from Server does not look like ember expects it? I am right now testing normalisations.For example, I try  Football.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({ overrides for normalize and normalizePayload here...But it seems, that the normalize functions are not being called. Am I on the wrong way?

Comment: You can create a per type serializer that fixes up the data into the format Ember Data expects.  Read the section labeled Rest Adapter and Serialization Configuration https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: Thats what I am trying all the time: Football.TeamSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractFindAll: function (store, type, payload) {
        alert(payload);... But the alert never fires... I thought, that this method will be called, when calling the find in the route...

Comment: That looks like it works to me, but you should use `extractArray` (for finding multiple records) and `extractSingle` (for finding a single record)  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/426/edit

Comment: Maybe I messed up my ember download. Am not sure anymore, if I downloaded the correct combination of data.js and ember.js. That could be one more reason, why I am struggeling here. I will just download the references from your example.

Comment: I'd hop to this version of ember data, http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.7/ember-data.js

Comment: hmm... I will quit for today...if you believe  it or not, when I copy and paste the code (html and javascript) I get the error : Error loading route Team.index...I even can not believe it by myself...But I can see from your sample that it works. I just dont know why i can not get it running on my local mashine.

Comment: Well, it seems that I have Problems, when i remove the Ajax-mock and run against my real json webservice. I tried to modify the mock-result with wrong Format, and as expected, the serialize-method gets called, I can see the alert. But when i run against my webservice, which also returns json, I get an error again with loading the route and no alert appears. That is what I dont understand. As far, as I understood, the method for extracting should get called, even when the json format is invalid for ember.

Comment: will you include the json being returned from your server in your original question above.

Comment: I think the json looks fine. I will later try to perform a call with normal JavaScript (without any frameworks) and then I will see, if that works. If not, I have to search the Problem somewhere else.

Comment: I solved my Problem: I added     jQuery.support.cors = true;
to my script. After that all workded as expected. Only in Firefox i am getting still Errors consuming the webservice. But basicly this is not an ember problem but something with jquery and my json-service.